# Jersey POST exception

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a SOAP ui at `localhost:1910/alerts` and I'm trying to do a post using it.

I have the folowing code, where 'alert' is an Object I want to send as Json:

```
    Client client = (Client) ClientBuilder.newClient( new ClientConfig().register( LoggingFilter.class ) );
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target("localhost:1910/alerts");

    Alert alert = new Alert();
    alert.setFailureDate("20200416090710");
    alert.setApplicationName("application_name");
    alert.setSeverity("high");
    alert.setEmailMessageBody("The application_name service has stopped");
    alert.addEmailToList("abc@gmail.com");
    alert.addEmailToList("def@gmail.com");

    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(alert, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```

When I run this code it breaks into the Invocation.Builder with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.accept(ClientRequest.java:336)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:221)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:59)
at br.com.main.Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

I was reading about and found out it may be a wrong version of some dependencie but  I'm struggling to find out which one. These are my Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.30.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

P.s: I'm running Java 8

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove `jersey-core` and `javax.ws.rs-api`. The first is for Jersey 1.x, while you are using 2.x. The second is a transitive and you might be pulling in the wrong version. As a general rule, dont add meaningless transitive dependencies to your pom.xml. Using different version often lean to this common NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: Awsome. Solved, thank you